# Tratar acentuação com Jquery

Tags: jquery, acentuação

Estou com problemas em tratar acentuação no jQuery.

Gostaria de remover acentos das palavras e substituir espaços por "%20".
Tentei fazer do jeito abaixo, porém, não funcionou.

```
cidade_sem_tratar = $('#estados').val();
console.log(cidade_sem_tratar);

cidade_tratada = cidade_sem_tratar
.replace(/[áàâã]/,'a')
.replace(/[éèê]/,'e')
.replace(/[óòôõ]/,'o')
.replace(/[úùû]/,'u')
.replace(' ','%20');
console.log(cidade_tratada);
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: problema de acentuação com jQuery]

Por gentileza, poderiam me ajudar?

Abraço e Obrigado!

Comment: Bom dia! Por que não cola o código na pergunta em vez de print? Assim poderíamos copiar e tentar reproduzir.

Comment: [Parece não ter problema com seu código](https://jsfiddle.net/h1btfu0n/)

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está correto na substituição dos acentos, mas para substituir TODOS os espaços, troque o último `replace` por:

```
.replace(/\s/g,'%20')
```

Do jeito que está, irá substituir apenas o primeiro espaço que for encontrado.

Veja funcionando:

```js
cidade_sem_tratar = $('#estados').val();
console.log(cidade_sem_tratar);

cidade_tratada = cidade_sem_tratar
.replace(/[áàâã]/,'a')
.replace(/[éèê]/,'e')
.replace(/[óòôõ]/,'o')
.replace(/[úùû]/,'u')
.replace(/\s/g,'%20');
console.log(cidade_tratada);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="estados" value="Afonso Cláudio" />
```

### Usando Função

```js
function remAcentos(v){
   var c='áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ';
   var s='aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC';
   var n = '';
   for(var x=0;x<v.length;x++){
      c.search(v.substr(x,1))>=0 ?
      n+=s.substr(c.search(v.substr(x,1)),1) :
      n+=v.substr(x,1);
   }
   return n;
}

cidade_sem_tratar = $('#estados').val();
console.log(cidade_sem_tratar);
cidade_tratada = remAcentos(cidade_sem_tratar).replace(/\s/g,'%20');
console.log(cidade_tratada);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="estados" value="Afonso Cláudio" />
```

Comment: Para tratar as palavras com acentuação não está funcionando.. mas em relação com os espaçamento está show! :) Mto obrigado

Comment: Pois é.. estou achando muito estranho esse erro. Vi que deu certo na sua simulação.. mas pra mim aparece como "Afonso%20Cláudio". Acento agudo no "á".

Comment: Não sei se é importante essa informação, mas, os dados eu estou pegando de um arquivo em JSON.

Comment: No inspecionar aparece sem acento..<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Afonso Claudio</span>"><span class="text">Afonso Cláudio</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>

Comment: O que será que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: É um seletor de cidades. Ele está sendo construido através de um arquivo em JSON.

Comment: @DiegoAlbuquerque Acho que não vai dar certo não. Tinha que ver o código de como vc tah pegando os dados do xml. Lá que tá o segredo.

Comment: Essa parte ajuda?              $.each(json.estados[_idEstado].cidades, function(indice){  

        $('#estados').append(
          '<option value="' + json.estados[_idEstado].cidades[indice] + '" ' + 
          (json.estados[_idEstado].cidades[indice] == _cidade ? 'selected="true"' : "") + 
          'data-uf="' + json.estados[_idEstado].sigla + '"' + '>' + 
              json.estados[_idEstado].cidades[indice]  +                   
          '</option>');
        });

Comment: O caso foi resolvido!! Muito obrigado pelo apoio e atenção!! :) O Rui Ferreira deu uma dica bem legal! Um abraço

Comment: @DiegoAlbuquerque Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se a função encodeURI faz o que quer, por exemplo:

```
var myStr = "Afonso Cláudio";
var res = encodeURI(myStr);
```

função para remover acentos:

```
function removerAcentos( newStringComAcento ) {
  var string = newStringComAcento;
  var mapaAcentosHex    = {
    a : /[\xE0-\xE6]/g,
    A : /[\xC0-\xC6]/g,
    e : /[\xE8-\xEB]/g,
    E : /[\xC8-\xCB]/g,
    i : /[\xEC-\xEF]/g,
    I : /[\xCC-\xCF]/g,
    o : /[\xF2-\xF6]/g,
    O : /[\xD2-\xD6]/g,
    u : /[\xF9-\xFC]/g,
    U : /[\xD9-\xDC]/g,
    c : /\xE7/g,
    C : /\xC7/g,
    n : /\xF1/g,
    N : /\xD1/g
};

for ( var letra in mapaAcentosHex ) {
    var expressaoRegular = mapaAcentosHex[letra];
    string = string.replace( expressaoRegular, letra );
}

return string;
}
```

Pode usar a função removerAcentos e depois encodeURI para colocar %20 nos espaços

Comment: Testei mas não funcionou.. quando ele vai tentar utilizar o nome da cidade depois de passar pelo encode ele aparece com acento na URL. Estou tentando achar um padrão para o site: http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/listaCidades?city=Afonso%20claudio .... Eu recebo o nome das cidades com acentos, ai eu trato e depois busco. O problema está acontecendo para tratar os nomes das cidades da forma que o site aceite (sem acentuação). Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Como está a fazer o post?

Comment: Funcionou!!!!!!!!!! Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Fico contente que tenha funcionado ;)

Answer (score 0):

O replace em javascript trabalha com regex, e vc n esta passando uma regex para trocar os espacos. tenta colocar assim:

```
string.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

Vc pode testar as regex em sites, como esse, por exemplo:
https://regex101.com/